# Can event delegation be implemented if the jQuery .on() receives only two parameters?

Tags: jquery

I am reading about delegated events at https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and http://api.jquery.com/on/. I was examining the following syntax:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

In order to implement event delegation, the optional `[, selector ]` in the syntax above must be used, correct? For example, this would not be implementing event delegation (notice how .on() is only receiving two parameters):

```
// Attach a directly bound event handler
$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

This is implementing event delegation (notice how .on() is receiving more than two parameters):

```
// Attach a delegated event handler
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Can event delegation be implemented if the jQuery .on() receives only two parameters? My impression is that it is not possible but I would like to have a confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: To be regarded as "delegated" an event handler must provide the "selector" argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it can. The optional selector parameter is checked against the event target behind the scenes, and executes the handler function only if there is a match. Nothing stopping you from writing your own delegation. For example:

```
$( "#list" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if( event.target.nodeName === a ) {
        console.log( $( this ).text() );
    }
});
```

But yes, this is probably pointless, and your understanding is mostly correct.